# Sample Standard Deviation vs. Population Standard Deviation

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

I have an HP 50g graphing calculator and I am using it to calculate the standard deviation of some data. In the statistics calculation there is a type which can have two values:

Sample
Population

I didn't change it, but I kept getting the wrong results for the standard deviation. When I changed it to "Population" type, I started getting correct results!

Why is that? As far as I know, there is only one type of standard deviation which is to calculate the root-mean-square of the values!

Did I miss something?

Comment: The [question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/54) @ CrossValidated.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

There are, in fact, two different formulas for standard deviation here: The population standard deviation $\sigma$ and the sample standard deviation $s$.

If $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_N$ denote all $N$ values from a population, then the (population) standard deviation is 
$$\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N (x_i - \mu)^2},$$
where $\mu$ is the mean of the population.

If $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_N$ denote $N$ values from a sample, however, then the (sample) standard deviation is 
$$s = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N-1} \sum_{i=1}^N (x_i - \bar{x})^2},$$
where $\bar{x}$ is the mean of the sample.

The reason for the change in formula with the sample is this: When you're calculating $s$ you are normally using $s^2$ (the sample variance) to estimate $\sigma^2$ (the population variance).  The problem, though, is that if you don't know $\sigma$ you generally don't know the population mean $\mu$, either, and so you have to use $\bar{x}$ in the place in the formula where you normally would use $\mu$.  Doing so introduces a slight bias into the calculation: Since $\bar{x}$ is calculated from the sample, the values of $x_i$ are on average closer to $\bar{x}$ than they would be to $\mu$, and so the sum of squares $\sum_{i=1}^N (x_i - \bar{x})^2$ turns out to be smaller on average than $\sum_{i=1}^N (x_i - \mu)^2$.  It just so happens that that bias can be corrected by dividing by $N-1$ instead of $N$.  (Proving this is a standard exercise in an advanced undergraduate or beginning graduate course in statistical theory.)  The technical term here is that $s^2$ (because of the division by $N-1$) is an *unbiased estimator* of $\sigma^2$.

Another way to think about it is that with a sample you have $N$ independent pieces of information.  However, since $\bar{x}$ is the average of those $N$ pieces, if you know $x_1 - \bar{x}, x_2 - \bar{x}, \ldots, x_{N-1} - \bar{x}$, you can figure out what $x_N - \bar{x}$ is.  So when you're squaring and adding up the residuals $x_i - \bar{x}$, there are really only $N-1$ independent pieces of information there.  So in that sense perhaps dividing by $N-1$ rather than $N$ makes sense.  The technical term here is that there are $N-1$ *degrees of freedom* in the residuals $x_i - \bar{x}$.

For more information, see Wikipedia's article on the [sample standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#With_sample_standard_deviation).

Comment: How does the formula $\frac{ \sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$ come from $s = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N-1} \sum_{i=1}^N (x_i - \bar{x})^2}$?

Comment: @Imray: It doesn't.  They refer to two different things.  The expression $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$ is the standard deviation of the mean $\bar{x}$ of the sample data.  The expression $s = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N-1} \sum_{i=1}^N (x_i - \bar{x})^2}$ is the standard deviation of the sample data (so not the mean of the sample data).

Comment: "Since x¯ is calculated from the sample, the values of xi are on average closer to x¯ than they would be to μ" -- oh wow, thank you. I've read the explanation based on df a number of times, but this suddenly makes it intuitively clear in a different way.

Comment: @MikeSpivey: Nice explanation. But if I know population mean μ then shouldn't I divide population variance by n-1 too?

Comment: @Durin: No.  If you actually know $\mu$ and you want to calculate $\sigma$ with all $N$ finite values from the population, then you're not estimating anything.  In this case $\sigma$ should be calculated using the straight-up average of the squared-deviations - dividing by $n$ instead of using the estimation-bias corrected version that divides by $n-1$.

Comment: So in this case why can't I understand it by the "N-1" independent pieces of information logic? I mean ok! I am not estimating this time but I am curious why the first logic wouldn't work here. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Isn't the convention normally to use $n$ for a sample, and $N$ for a population?

Comment: Could you give a link to the proof  of "It just so happens that that bias can be corrected by dividing..."?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. That part about `N-1` independent pieces of information does not look convincing since you could apply the same logic to `σ`, but you don't, you apply it only to `s`.