# biased Maximum Likelihood estimation

Tags: probability, statistics, parameter-estimation

Given $N$ points ($x_k$, k from $1$ to $N$) generated from a normal distribution (1-dimensional case) with known mean $\mu$, the Maximum Likelihood estimation of the variance is $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (x_k-\mu)^2$.

How is it justified that this estimation is biased for finite N?

thanks,
Nikos

Comment: MLEs are not required to be unbiased. I'm confused as to what you're asking.

Comment: Since $\mu$ is known, $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N(x_k - \mu)^2$ _is_ an unbiased estimator for $\sigma^2$.  If $\mu$ is unknown and the sample mean $\bar{x} =\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N x_k$ is used instead, then $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N(x_k - \bar{x})^2$ is a biased estimator for $\sigma^2$.

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate: But in the text i am reading currently, it is explicitly mentioned that in the ML case the estimation is unbiased only asymptotically and not for finite $N$

Comment: "in the ML case the estimation is unbiased only asymptotically and not for finite $N$" is perfectly correct.  If the mean $\mu$ is unknown, the ML estimator for $\sigma^2$ is $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N(x_k - \bar{x})^2$ and _is_ biased. It is asymptotically unbiased as $N \to \infty$. (The unbiased estimator in this case is $\frac{1}{N-1}\sum_{k=1}^N(x_k - \bar{x})^2$).  But your question specifically stated that $\mu$ is known and in this case _(which is different from the case of unknown $\mu$)_, the ML estimator for $\sigma^2$ is what you said, and it is unbiased for all $N$.

Comment: in the text it is said that the expectation of the ML estimation of the variance is equal to: $1/N\sum_{k=1}^NE[(x_k - \mu)^2] = ((N-1)/N)\sigma$ all that for known $\mu$

Comment: What text is this?  and are you absolutely sure you have copied what your text says _exactly?_  e.g. $\sigma$ instead of $\sigma^2$?

Comment: If that's what the book said, then I suspect the book was treating the case where $\mu$ is not known but has to be estimated.  Certainly in the case where $\mu$ has to be estimated, the MLE is biased.

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate: no, it says $\sigma^2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filling in some details left out of the comments by @Michael Hardy, @zyx, and
myself, suppose $\vec{X} = (X_1, \ldots, X_N)$ where the $X_i, 1 \leq i \leq N,$ are independent $N(\mu, v)$ random variables with known mean $\mu$ and unknown  *variance* $v$.  The joint density function is 
$$f_{\vec{X}}(\vec{x}) = (2\pi v)^{-N/2}\exp(-a/v) ~\text{where}~ \vec{x} = (x_1, \ldots, x_N)~ \text{and}~ a = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^N (x_i - \mu)^2.$$ 
If $\vec{X}$ is observed to have value $\vec{x}$, the likelihood function is
$L(v) =  (2\pi v)^{-N/2}\exp(-a/v)$ and it is easy to show that $L(v)$
attains maximum value at 
$$v = \frac{2a}{N} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N (x_i - \mu)^2$$
and so the maximum likelihood estimator (MLE)  of $v$ is $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N (x_i - \mu)^2$.  We have
$$
E\left [ \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N (X_i - \mu)^2 \right ] 
= \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N E[(X_i - \mu)^2] =  \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N v = v, 
$$
and thus, contrary to any alleged claims in an unspecified textbook in the possession of Nikos, the MLE for $v$ *is unbiased* in this instance.

What if $\mu$ is also unknown?  The likelihood function is now
$$
L(\mu, v) 
= (2\pi v)^{-N/2}\exp\left [ -\frac{1}{2v}\sum_{i=1}^N (x_i - \mu)^2\right ]
$$
and has a global maximum at
$$
(\mu, v)  = \left (\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N x_i,
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \left (x_i -\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N x_i \right)^2 \right )
= \left ( \bar{x}, \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N  (x_i -\bar{x})^2 \right ).$$
The MLE for $v$ is thus $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N  (x_i -\bar{x})^2$
and *is biased* since
$$
E\left [ \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \left (X_i -\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N X_i \right)^2 \right ] = \left(\frac{N-1}{N}\right)v
$$
but, as noted by Nikos's textbook, the MLE for $v$ is *asymptotically
unbiased* in the limit as $N \to \infty$.  On the other hand, it should
be obvious from the above description that
$\frac{1}{N-1}\sum_{i=1}^N  (x_i -\bar{x})^2$ is an unbiased
estimator for $v$ for all $N \geq 2$.

Comment: the textbook in question is: Pattern Recognition, 4th ed. by S.Theodoridis, K. Koutroumbas. If you happen to have it in your possesion take a look at p. 35 and 37

Comment: Actually, the $N(\mu,v)$ density is proportional to $\exp(-(x-\mu)^2/(2v))$.  You're missing a "2" in the denominator.

Comment: @MichaelHardy  I thought I included the $2$ in the denominator as part of the quantity I called $a$.  Is there a $2$ missing elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The "bias for finite N" is for a different estimator where $\mu$ is replaced by $\overline{x} = \frac{x_1 + \cdots + x_N}{N}$. If the "true" value of $\mu$ is given the estimator in the question is unbiased.

This was the subject of an earlier question,

[Intuitive Explanation of Bessel's Correction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61251/intuitive-explanation-of-bessels-correction/61369#61369)

and in my answer there it is explained why the calculation with $\mu$ is unbiased.

Comment: This is wrong in this case.  Maximum likelihood estimators are typically biased, but this one is not.

Comment: @Michael: I missed the $\mu$, since the question talked about "bias for finite N" which exists only if $\overline{x}$ is meant. See edit.

Comment: @Michael: one can also see from the comments, where a factor of N-1 appears in a formula with $\mu$, that either the question or the textbook is using $\mu$ where the semantics dictate $\overline{x}$ as the correct reading.

Comment: @zyx: It's not only that it uses $\mu$ as a symbol but it is also explicitly mentioned in the formulation of the problem that $\mu$ is known

Comment: Nikos, where you wrote "in the text it is said that the expectation of the ML estimation of the variance is equal to: $1/N\sum_{k=1}^NE[(x_k - \mu)^2] = ((N-1)/N)\sigma^2 \quad $", the factor of (N-1) can appear only if $\mu$ is *unkown* and therefore estimated using the $x_i$.  So the question and/or the book does use $\mu$ as a symbol, but the notion of "bias for finite N" and the formula you wrote down, make sense only if $\mu$ is interpreted as the name for an unknown parameter that is estimated by $\overline{x} = (x_1 + \cdots + x_N)/N$.