# Simplified formula for standard deviation does not work

Tags: statistics

I was given the following sample {9,8 ; 10,2 ; 10,4 ; 9,8 ; 10 ; 10,2 ; 9,6}. So if I compute the mean I obtain 10. If I compute the standard deviation with:

$\sqrt{\frac{1}{6} \sum{(x_i-10)^2}}$

I obtain 0,2828. But if first I compute the mean of the squared values, which gives 100,0685714, and then use the formula:

$\sqrt{100,0685714 - 10^2}$

I obtain 0,2618. Where is my mistake?

**EDIT**

I found the reason of the error. If I divide by 7 instead of 6 (population mean), both formulas give the same. Which brings new questions. Does the second formula works only while using the **population formula**? Is there a 'simplified formula' to compute faster the **sample error**, like the one I used in the second case?

Comment: See [Intuitive Explanation of Bessel's Correction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61251/intuitive-explanation-of-bessels-correction) and links therein.

Comment: Next time try to use [math-jax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @DavisJohnson FYI, re: your edit comment of "The commas should be decimal places", please see [Countries using decimal comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Countries_using_decimal_comma) versus [Countries using decimal point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Countries_using_decimal_point). I also suggest that you at least scan, if not fully read, the rest of the Wikipedia article.

Comment: @tac Apologies for the confusion. Use the link on [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and make the necessary edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the former expression you have for the standard deviation is $\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum(x_i-\bar{x})^2}$. If we decompose what's inside, we get:

\begin{aligned}
\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum({x_i^2}-2x_i\bar{x}+\bar{x}^2)}&=  \sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\left(\sum{x_i^2}-n\bar{x}^2\right)} \\&=   \sqrt{\sum\frac{{x_i^2}}{n-1}-\frac{n}{n-1}\bar{x}^2}
\end{aligned}

While not as simple as the version for the population standard deviation, it isn't too bad. There may be a simpler expression I'm not aware of.

Comment: Did you distribute the square over the sum?

Comment: @tac Yes. I edited my response to include that part. See if you can work out the algebraic manipulation to get the final expression.

Comment: @tac now that I'm looking at your sample data, it looks like you have 7 observations. But in your edit, you're saying you should've divided by 7 instead of 6. So were you supposed to use the population sample SD?

Comment: If I divide by 7 both formulas give the same, but if I divide by 6 the formulas dos not give the same. No, I need to find the mean of the sample

Comment: @tac the only way both formulas will give you the same answer when dividing by 6 is if you use the formula in my response.

Comment: $\sqrt{\frac{n}{n-1}}\sqrt{\frac{\sum {x_i^2}}n-\bar{x}^2}$ is an alternative presentation which makes Bessel's correction more explicit